# How to capture the last change(very recently happened) change in document

Tags: jquery, dom

As in the Question text, how can I get the last action performed on document using jQuery.
For example I have changed element class as below

```
  $('.highlight').toggleClass();
```

How can know that which element was the target of last change in a document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom event and trigger it each time ?

```
$('.highlight').toggleClass().trigger('somethingChanged')
```

Then listen for the triggered event

```
$(document).bind('somethingChanged', data, function(){ do stuff });
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/